# C# inheritance doesn't behave as I expect it to

Tags: c#, inheritance, decorator

I'm going through head first design patterns, but I'm coding the examples in C# instead of java. I coded decorator pattern, but I'm getting some strange bug that I can't figure out how to fix. 
Line 1 runs as expected, and the description is "Dark Roast", however line two changes the description to "unknown beverage" instead of the expected "Dark Roast, Mocha." How do I fix this behavior?

Main program:

```
beverage = new DarkRoast();
beverage = new Mocha(beverage);
beverage = new Mocha(beverage);
Console.WriteLine(beverage.Description + " $" + beverage.Cost);
```

Decorator code:

```
namespace DecoratorPattern
{
    public abstract class Beverage
    {
        public abstract double Cost { get; }

        public string Description { get; set; } = "unknown beverage";
    }

    public class DarkRoast : Beverage
    {
        public DarkRoast()
        {
            Description = "Dark Roast";
        }

        public override double Cost => .99;
    }

    public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
    {
        public abstract string Description { get; }
    }

    public class Mocha : CondimentDecorator
    {
        Beverage beverage;

        public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
        {
            this.beverage = beverage;
        }

        public override string Description
        {
            get { return beverage.Description + ", Mocha"; }
        }

        public override double Cost => .20 + beverage.Cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Main program doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't marked the `Description` property as `virtual` in the `Beverage` class. Therefore if your variable `beverage` is a `Beverage` the `Description` property will always be read from there. The value will always be the default unknown.

Just remove the `abstract` declaration from the `CondimentDecorator` class and add `virtual` to the base class, then your override will work.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I kept it abstract because the idea is to force the classes that implement it to write out implementation. Thanks for pointing and explaining the problem.

Comment: Then what is the point of `CondimentDecorator` class if you remove `abstract` property from it? If so, you are able to remove `CondimentDecorator` completely and inherit `Mocha` directly from `Beverage` and still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You're hiding the original `Description` property in `CondimentDecorator`, making a new property `Description` on top of it, if you change the type to a `CondimentDecorator` then you will get the expected result.

This should print the value you are expecting:

```
 var result = (CondimentDecorator) beverage;
 Console.WriteLine(result.Description);
```

You need to change the base to be abstract or virtual and override it on the inheriting classes

```
public abstract class Beverage
{
    public abstract double Cost { get; }

    public virtual Description { get; set; } = "unknown beverage";
}
```

At this point you don't need an additional decorator class just override the method in the base object

```
public class Mocha : Beverage
{
    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get { return beverage.Description + ", Mocha"; }
        set { throw InvalidOperationException("Cannot Set Value of Decorator"); }
    }

    public override double Cost => .20 + beverage.Cost;
}
```